Can magus use knowledge pool from previous day?
Magus arcane pool reads:

At 1st level, the magus gains a reservoir of mystical arcane energy
that he can draw upon to fuel his powers and enhance his weapon. This
arcane pool has a number of points equal to 1/2 his magus level
(minimum 1) + his Intelligence modifier. The pool refreshes once per
day when the magus prepares his spells.

And Knowledge pool states:

At 7th level, when a magus prepares his magus spells, he can
decide to expend 1 or more points from his arcane pool, up to his
Intelligence bonus. For each point he expends, he can treat any one
spell from the magus spell list as if it were in his spellbook and can
prepare that spell as normal that day. If he does not cast spells
prepared in this way before the next time he prepares spells, he loses
those spells. He can also cast spells added in this way using his
spell recall ability, but only until he prepares spells again.

Which comes first, the refresh of arcana pool or Knowledge pool ability trigger? Can the character choose? Can a magus use leftover arcana pool from previous day, after a nights rest, to prepare a spell which is in magus spell list, but not on character's spellbook?

Its not defined, but it's probably not meant to work
The sentence

The pool refreshes once per day when the magus prepares his spells.

is the only statement we have about the point in time when the pool refreshes.
There are no general rules for at what time something triggers "when" something happens, if that something has an extended duration, and preparing the spells has an extended duration of 1 hour:

A magus may know any number of spells. He must choose and prepare his spells ahead of time by getting 8 hours of sleep and spending 1 hour studying his spellbook. While studying, the magus decides which spells to prepare.

So we are stuck with it not being defined if they get back their pool at the start of that hour (in which case they could not use old pool), or sometime during that hour, in which case they could still use old pool to add spells.
Looking at the section on arcane spells in the magic rules, it has a subsection on wizard spell preparation. This works very similarly, but is laid out in more detail:

Rest: To prepare his daily spells, a wizard must first sleep for 8 hours. [...] Spell Preparation Time: After resting, a wizard must study his spellbook to prepare any spells that day. If he wants to prepare all his spells, the process takes 1 hour.

The magus also can copy spells from wizard spell books and is using a spellbook, so the way they acquire magic is clearly modeled after the wizard, even though of course, he or she is not a wizard per se.
Now, that section contains the following detail of how spell prep works:

Recent Casting Limit/Rest Interruptions: If a wizard has cast spells recently, the drain on his resources reduces his capacity to prepare new spells. When he prepares spells for the coming day, all the spells he has cast within the last 8 hours count against his daily limit.

That is a mechanism that explicitly bars the wizard from "casting off" old, unused spell slots at the beginning of spell preparation (for example, by casting mage armor for the coming day with old slots), to overcome the daily spell limit count.
I think given how similar these classes operate in their spell preparation, I'd expect the same idea should apply here, and using old pool to overcome the dayily limit of spells is not how it is meant to work, and would rule it that way.
But the rules do not tell us, so it is up to your GM to decide.
